# Angular nz-dropdown-menu dynamic parameters

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, ng-zorro-antd

I would like to have a dynamic parameter based on a dropdown list:

So this is my code:

```
     <input
        #file
        type="file" 
        (change)="functionTest($event.target)"/>
      <button
        nz-button
        nz-dropdown
        [nzDropdownMenu]="menu">
           Import
      </button>
      <nz-dropdown-menu #menu="nzDropdownMenu">
        <ul nz-menu>
          <li nz-menu-item (click)="file.click()">
            TEST1
          </li>
          <li nz-menu-item (click)="file.click()">
            TEST2
         </li> ....
```

So I call `functionTest` with the $event.target (file that I choose ) but I want to add an argument depends on which button I clicked, For examples if I click on `Test1` I want to call
`functionTest($event.target, 'Test1')`

What is the best way for doing this, without using or getting element directly from the DOM because direct manipulation of the DOM can lead to security, performance, and maintainability issues.

I could add an other function in the (click) but I'm not sure it's the best way for this

Is it possible or do I need to stop using nz-dropdown-menu?
I'm using TypeScript

Thanks in advance